# How to adding data in loop and display chart dynamically like in live (chart.js & typescript & angular)?

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

I have a very big problem with chart.js in typescript  in angular. After a long battle, I was able to display the chart in the application. The chart displays in the program and looks fine, but it is a static graph.

Now, however, I would like to be able to display the graph in continuous form something like in live. Can anyone give me a hint on my code as an example, how could I implement it?

I would like to achieve a sine wave like in this example http://jsfiddle.net/9ornvbLp/1/ (but have alternating values ​​like 0, 1, 0, 1 or -1, 1, -1, 1).

**My code in .ts file:**

```
/* Scatter chart options */
  chartOptionsSocket123_Scatter = {

    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,

    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'bottom',

        /* Display grid lines */
        display: true,

        /* X-axis min and max range */
        ticks: {
          display: false,
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],

      /* Y Axis */
      yAxes: [{
        /* Display grid lines */
        display: true,

        /* Y-axis min and max range */
        ticks: {

          /* Min and Max value */
          suggestedMax: 6,
          suggestedMin: -6,

          /* Hide value on Y-axis */
          display: false
        }

        /* On grid Y lines */
        // gridLines: {
        //   display: true
        // }
      }]
    },

    /* Off dotPoint */
    elements: {
      point: {
        radius: 0
      }
    },

    /* Off legend */
    legend: {
      display: false
    },

    /* Stop cut off chart at top */
    layout: {
      padding: {
        top: 10,
        bottom: 10
      }
    },
  };

  chartDatasetsSocket12_ImpulseType1 = [
    {
      data: [{ x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 1, y: 0 }, { x: 3, y: 2 }, { x: 5, y: 2 }, { x: 7, y: 4 },
      { x: 9, y: 4 }, { x: 11, y: 6 }, { x: 11, y: 0 }, { x: 12, y: 0 }],

      fill: false,
      showLine: true,
      lineTension: 0,
      borderWidth: 8,
      borderColor: '#d70000'
    }
  ];
```

**My code in HTML file:**

```
<canvas class="scatter_chart_size" baseChart
[chartType]="'scatter'"
[datasets]="chartDatasetsSocket12_ImpulseType1 "
[options]="chartOptionsSocket123_Scatter">
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do exactly the same thing like your example. Through the interval, you update the dataset of your chart and request chartjs to update it. From my point of view, try to connect with a canvas through its id, if you don't need to support Angular Universal, feel free to use `document.getElementById()`. The idea is you prepare the data inside your component and frequently update your chart by the new data.

Import ChartJS into your component:

`import * as Chart from 'chart.js';`

Update chart into your canvas

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('chart');

if (canvas) {
  const ctx = (canvas as HTMLCanvasElement).getContext('2d');
  this.chart = this.buildChart(ctx);
}
```

Inside the `buildChart`:

```
buildChart(ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
    return new Chart(ctx, {// place your configuration here});
}
```